# picking jwt token from cookie not the request

Tags: java

I am storing JWT token in the  ResponseCookie with the sign in request but all other requests are authenticated without passing the Bearer token as it is getting picked up from the ResponseCookie and I dont think this is a usual flow of authentication.

I think all other requests should use the bearer token not the token from cookie storing the token

Comment: It is perfectly fine to store access tokens in cookies. Is the behavior you experience unexpected?

Comment: Pretty standard to store jwt in browser as cookie. Just make it httpOnly and secure. Note that JWT implies sessionless, csrf is not a threat.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.